# Has anyone moved an azure web site that uses table storage to sql server?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, azure

I need to move an application from Azure to local servers behind the client's firewall.  The application uses a web role, a worker role and storage (table, blob and queue).

Moving the web and worker roles is pretty straightforward.  Moving the storage components opens up many options.

Has anyone been through this, even if the end result was not to move.  Target storage options seem to include SQL Server or nosql databases such as MongoDB or RavenDB.

Comment: Yes, surely someone once tried this. Does that answer your question? No? Then please tell us what exactly you want to know.

Comment: Thanks Philipp.  So, I am going to use SQL Server.  I am going to create tables on an as-needed basis to store serialised instances of my classes that inherit from TableEntity.  I am going to create tables called "[Class Type]=[Partition Key]".  I am going to have two fields in each table: VarChar[32] for the index (this is the Row Key) and VarChar for the serialised class.  I am going to serialise the instances using NewtonSoft Json Serializer with a default contract resolver to ensure that only the properties that table storage would have saved are saved.  Any code for creating the tables?

Comment: This comment completely changed your question. Please edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Tables [ARE NOT SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553018.aspx).  Azure Table Storage is a flexible key/value store, which has no set schema, as opposed to SQL, which is a structured, relational, transactional database.  Different rows within the same table can have different structures in Table Storage.  Therefore, there is no direct migration path for the data.

Mongodb is a Document Database, where the data is represented as a collection of objects, nearly identical to the representation in your application.  While similar to Azure Tables in the respect that the data is not relational, it would be very inefficient to store key/value pairs in Mongodb.  Like SQL Server, a direct migration path from Azure Tables to Mongodb is unlikely.

Ultimately, the data storage will likely need to be go through an architecture change to move to another storage system which does not rely upon row key / partition key hierarchy.